# How to render a modal using express and handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, node-modules

How can I render a modal using `express` and `handlebars`, I have an `index.js` file which handles all the routes. When I'm in `main.handlebars` file I would like to click a button and pop out a modal with a form without changing the background page route.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about your route files.
On the handlebar file first add a modal somewhere and invoke it using a button as like :

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary " type="button" data-toggle="modal" href="" data-target="#add_food">
                  <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>&nbsp;Add Food
                </button>
```

The modal can be as follows:

```
 <div class="modal inmodal fade" id="add_food" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

Comment: I have an app that displays a list of posts, The post owner user can edit the post, instead of open a new page form to allow him to edit I would like to just pop out a modal with a form so he can edit without open a new page.